# jQuery post error 'must be of type String'

Tags: jquery, json, post, request

Trying to post the value of an input field, to '/confirm' as JSON, but I get an error in the console. `"description must be of type String"`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $form = $(".js-form");

  $form.on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var desc = $form.find( "input[name='description']" ).val();
    var url = "/confirm";

    $.post(url, {description: desc}, function(response){
      console.log(response)
    }, "json");

  });
});
```

I expect the response to be successful as I'm posting a string

Comment: Check what value is held in `desc`, and also what is actually being received on the server side

Comment: desc is definitely a string, response is an object but I don't understand why

Comment: Please post the full error. It's not clear where that error is coming from, since jQuery would not typically complain about a property like that.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://api.jquery.com/find/) link jquery.find function returns an array of elements, so you should use it like this:

```
var desc = $form.find( "input[name='description']" )[0].value;
```

Comment: If I print the type of `desc` to the console, it states it is a string.

Comment: `val()` will return the value of the first element in the list of elements defined by the jQuery object (and a jQuery object is not an array; it's array-like).